# Reply, ReplyAll and Forward buttons are not appearing on EmailMessage layout of claim related record

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

EmailMessage record is created/inserted from apexclass implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler

```
          fromAddress is from external mail - @gmail
          Snippet here :- Related to is claim id

        EmailMessage emailMsg = new EmailMessage();
        emailMsg.ToAddress=(toAddress);
        emailMsg.FromAddress=inboundEmail.fromAddress;
        emailMsg.Subject=inboundEmail.subject;
        emailMsg.HtmlBody=inboundEmail.htmlBody; 
        emailMsg.TextBody=inboundEmail.plainTextBody;
        emailMsg.Status = '0';
        emailMsg.RelatedToId = claim_temp.Id;
```

[without the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwZyZ.png),
if relatedto is case id then i can see
[with the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykSTe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Allow Activities" ticked on that Claim object? Will be in object's "header" config, next to "Allow Reports". Sending emails out is part of the Task/Event functionality.

Is that in same sandbox? If it's different environments - you might have Setup -> Deliverability turned off.

Comment: Claim object is an standard object, I can't edit it. The issue/the screen shots attached are from same org.

Comment: You use Financial Services Cloud plugin? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_object_reference.meta/financial_services_cloud_object_reference/sforce_api_objects_claim.htm ? If it's not editable you might have to raise a ticket with FinServ support why it's not marked for "allow activities"